# What does all the fields for db.part/db mean?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm a newbie to datomic and I'm still trying to figure out how the system has been built. In particular, I don't understand what role :db.part/db plays as it seems to be needed every time a schema is installed. Could somebody shed some light on what this all means?

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d])
(def uri "datomic:mem://sample")
(d/create-database uri)
(def conn (d/connect uri))

(pprint (seq (d/entity dbval :db.part/db)))

;; => 
;; ([:db/doc "Name of the system partition. The system partition includes the core of datomic, as well as user schemas: type definitions, attribute definitions, partition definitions, and data function definitions."]
;;  [:db.install/function #{:db.fn/cas :db.fn/retractEntity}]
;;  [:db.install/attribute
;;   #{:db/noHistory :db.install/partition :db/cardinality
;;     :db.install/attribute :db/index :db/unique :db/fulltext
;;     :db/txInstant :db/lang :db/doc :db.install/valueType :db/code
;;     :db/isComponent :db/fn :db.install/function :db/valueType :db/ident
;;     :fressian/tag}]
;;  [:db.install/valueType
;;   #{:db.type/uuid :db.type/bigint :db.type/uri :db.type/ref
;;     :db.type/keyword :db.type/bytes :db.type/string :db.type/instant
;;     :db.type/fn :db.type/long :db.type/bigdec :db.type/boolean
;;     :db.type/double :db.type/float}]
;;  [:db.install/partition #{:db.part/db}]
;;  [:db/ident :db.part/db])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:db.part/db` is the partition for schema entities (see the schema docs on [partitions](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html#sec-2)). These db.install attributes are used to trigger hooks on the installation of certain entities. That they are asserted of `:db.part/db` has no special significance (afaik), this is just the convention the Datomic team chose for representing the installation of attributes, etc.

So, e.g., when you submit a transaction like:

```
[{:db/ident :person/name
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/valueType :db.type/string
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db
  :db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]}]
```

which is equivalent to (in Clojure now instead of edn):

```
(let [id (datomic.api/tempid :db.part/db)]
  [[:db/add id :db/ident :person/name]
   [:db/add id :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one]
   [:db/add id :db/valueType :db.type/string]
   [:db/add :db.part/db :db.install/attribute id]])
```

then Datomic notices you have added a value for `:db.part/db`'s `:db.install/attribute`, validating that you provided the required attributes for an attribute, and installing the new attribute into the database so you can use it after the transaction.

Similarly, you can use `:db.install/_partition :db.part/db` to install new partitions. See the docs on [Installing an attribute definition](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html#sec-1-4) and [Creating new partitions](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html#sec-2-1).

`:db.install/valueType` could someday be used to install your own custom value types, but this feature is not ready yet. `:db.install/function` appears to be for internal use. I am not sure of its purpose. The documented way to [install database functions](http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html#sec-1-2) is different.

These attributes (except for `:db.install/function`) are also convenient for queries and inspecting the db. For example, we can pull out the set of all the installed value types, in case we forgot:

```
user> (:db.install/valueType (datomic.api/entity db :db.part/db))
#{:db.type/uuid :db.type/bigint :db.type/uri :db.type/ref
  :db.type/keyword :db.type/bytes :db.type/string :db.type/instant
  :db.type/fn :db.type/long :db.type/bigdec :db.type/boolean
  :db.type/double :db.type/float}
```

Or we can write queries over the existing attributes:

```
user> (datomic.api/q '[:find ?ns (distinct ?attr) :where
                       [:db.part/db :db.install/attribute ?a]
                       [?a :db/ident ?attr]
                       [(namespace ?attr) ?ns]]
                     db)
[["db" #{:db/noHistory :db/cardinality :db/index :db/unique
         :db/fulltext :db/txInstant :db/lang :db/doc
         :db/code :db/isComponent :db/fn :db/valueType
         :db/ident}]
 ["db.install" #{:db.install/partition :db.install/attribute
                 :db.install/valueType :db.install/function}]
 ["fressian" #{:fressian/tag}]]
```